# Android Studio using jars

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, android-studio

I'm new on Android Studio since I've used Eclipse till now. Now I'm trying to import two libraries (MPChartLib and datetimepicker-library) as a jar.

The steps I did:
1. Create a folder called libraries
2. Drag and drop the jars to the folder
3. Right click on them --> Add to library (something like that)
(As I have seen on some tutorials)

The system recognizes those jars and I am able to work with them. But when I want to run the project, I get the following error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportGridlayoutV72100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK   

C:\Users\Markus\Documents\AndroidStudiosWORKSPACE\TestProject\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-    unaligned.apk
Path in archive: res/values/colors.xml
Origin 1:     C:\Users\Markus\Documents\AndroidStudiosWORKSPACE\TestProject\app\libraries\datetimepicker-library.jar
Origin 2:     C:\Users\Markus\Documents\AndroidStudiosWORKSPACE\TestProject\app\libraries\MPChartLib.jar
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
android {
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'res/values/colors.xml'
  }
}
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK res/values/colors.xml
File 1:     C:\Users\Markus\Documents\AndroidStudiosWORKSPACE\TestProject\app\libraries\datetimepicker-library.jar
File 2:     C:\Users\Markus\Documents\AndroidStudiosWORKSPACE\TestProject\app\libraries\datetimepicker-library.jar
```

It's not the first time I get this error, so I have searched for a solution for hours - vainly.
The following is my build.gradle where I have already excluded many files:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        exclude 'bin/AndroidManifest.xml'
        exclude 'bin/R.txt'
        exclude 'bin/jarlist.cache'
        exclude 'build.gradle'
        exclude 'proguard-project.txt'
        exclude 'project.properties'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nomax.gymdiary"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile files('libraries/datetimepicker-library.jar')
    compile files('libraries/MPChartLib.jar')
}
```

I'm sure that I don't have to exclude those important files (which can be seen on latest error where I also have to exclude res/values/colors.xml)

Greetings from Austria!

PS: I have exported the libs from an android project from Eclipse to a jar file. Can this be the problem?

Comment: You dont have to copy the jars in the lib folder. Just include the path in your gradle file in the dependencies section. I think you have done both that is why you getting the duplicate error

Comment: I am sorry I am a noob on gradle (and on Android Studio) - Where should the jars be in that case? And I have to write in the build.gradle of the app something like dependencies { compile '...' }, right?

Comment: Yup u pretty much right.Jars have to be in your workspace. this is what worked for me. I deleted from the lib folder and just wrote in the build.gradle.You can check some example and proceed through

Comment: I've tried it but it's still not working. That's so troublesome because I have tried so many things and even google cannot show me the solution... It seems I am the only one who has the problem (There are few problems which look like the same but the solution for them works not for me). Maybe I should reinstall everything :D - Nevertheless thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome! well I had the same problem and I solved it accordingly. It is actually the error where android is encountering some jars twice.

Comment: I finally found the problem! My problem was that I thought I can easily export a Android project from Eclipse to a jar file and then  import it to the Android Studio. Downloading the prepared jar / compile with the given gradle uri solved it... finally!